# BigTable schema design

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Playing around with BigTable and trying to understand if my schema design has flaws.

We have thousands of sensors that are submitting data with different frequencies. Between once a second and every 15 seconds or slower.

My idea is to have `sensorId:year-month` as a row key, a static name "data" as the family and multiple columns to split the data in buckets of days for example.

[image]

So there should be no hotspotting, rows wont grow too large. Is there anything wrong with this approach? Im not sure, if creating those "1-10" and "16-31" columns makes sense, but having all data in one column doesnt feel right as well. Additionally having these "day-bucket" columns would help keeping column data below 10MB

UI-wise this data is usually queried like "show me the data for sensors A, B, C for the past 1 day, 1 week, 1 month".

Answer (score 0):

I think you schema design is correct according to the [BigTable best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design).

Specially when it comes about what this documentation states about rows:

- **Don't store more than 100 MB of data in a single row**. Rows that exceed this limit can result in reduced read performance.
- **Keep all information for an entity in a single row.**
- **Store related entities in adjacent rows**, to make reads more efficient.

Also regarding to columns you are following too the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#columns) by avoiding using too many columns in any single row.

Nonetheless once you have created your schema you can analyze it with the [Key Visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/keyvis-overview) which will help you to figure out it your performance is good.

Comment: I ended up having keys like that:

sensorId#timestamp

each key has just one column with the value of the given timestamp